# Как подружить fixed с transform?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Мне нужно прибить синий блок к потолку, но из за того, что content имеет свойство transform, fixed(синий блок) начинает отображаться от самой высокой точки сайта, а не от потолка браузера. Как это можно исправить?

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

smoothScroll("#content");



const horizontalSections = gsap.utils.toArray('.horizontal')

horizontalSections.forEach(function (sec, i) {  
  
  var thisPinWrap = sec.querySelector('.pin-wrap');
  var thisAnimWrap = thisPinWrap.querySelector('.animation-wrap');
  
  var getToValue = () => -(thisAnimWrap.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth); 

  gsap.fromTo(thisAnimWrap, { 
    x: () => thisAnimWrap.classList.contains('to-right') ? 0 : getToValue() 
  }, { 
    x: () => thisAnimWrap.classList.contains('to-right') ? getToValue() : 0, 
    ease: "none",
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: sec,   
      start: "top top",
      end: () => "+=" + (thisAnimWrap.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth),
      pin: true,
      invalidateOnRefresh: true,
      scrub: true,
    }
  });

}); 


function smoothScroll(content, viewport, smoothness) {
  content = gsap.utils.toArray(content)[0];
  smoothness = smoothness || 1;

  gsap.set(viewport || content.parentNode, {overflow: "hidden", position: "fixed", height: "100%", width: "100%", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0});
  gsap.set(content, {overflow: "visible", width: "100%"});

  let getProp = gsap.getProperty(content),
    setProp = gsap.quickSetter(content, "y", "px"),
    setScroll = ScrollTrigger.getScrollFunc(window),
    removeScroll = () => content.style.overflow = "visible",
    killScrub = trigger => {
      let scrub = trigger.getTween ? trigger.getTween() : gsap.getTweensOf(trigger.animation)[0];
      scrub && scrub.kill();
      trigger.animation.progress(trigger.progress);
    },
    height, isProxyScrolling;

  function refreshHeight() {
    height = content.clientHeight;
    content.style.overflow = "visible"
    document.body.style.height = height + "px";
    return height - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  }

  ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refresh", () => {
    removeScroll();
    requestAnimationFrame(removeScroll);
  })
  ScrollTrigger.defaults({scroller: content});
  ScrollTrigger.prototype.update = p => p; 

  ScrollTrigger.scrollerProxy(content, {
    scrollTop(value) {
      if (arguments.length) {
        isProxyScrolling = true;
        setProp(-value);
        setScroll(value);
        return;
      }
      return -getProp("y");
    },
    getBoundingClientRect() {
      return {top: 0, left: 0, width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
    }
  });

  return ScrollTrigger.create({
    animation: gsap.fromTo(content, {y:0}, {
      y: () => document.documentElement.clientHeight - height,
      ease: "none",
      onUpdate: ScrollTrigger.update
    }),
    scroller: window,
    invalidateOnRefresh: true,
    start: 0,
    end: refreshHeight,
    refreshPriority: -999,
    scrub: smoothness,
    onUpdate: self => {
      if (isProxyScrolling) {
        killScrub(self);
        isProxyScrolling = false;
      }
    },
    onRefresh: killScrub
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
          var $menu = $("#catsecmenu");
          $(window).scroll(function(){
              if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $menu.hasClass("defaulttm") ){
              $menu.removeClass("defaulttm").addClass("catsecmenufx");
              } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 100 && $menu.hasClass("catsecmenufx")) {
              $menu.removeClass("catsecmenufx").addClass("defaulttm");
              }
          });
      });
```

```css
/* devanagari */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJbecmNE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJnecmNE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* devanagari */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z11lFc-K.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1JlFc-K.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1xlFQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* devanagari */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z11lFc-K.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z1JlFc-K.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z1xlFQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    height: 100px;
    background: #000
}
.videobanner {
    height: 619px;
    background: #ccc
}
.section2 {
    height: 500px;
    background: #333
}
.section3 {
    height: 500px;
    background: #e1e1e1
}
.section4 {
    height: 400px;
    background: #000
}
.catsecmenu {
    height: 55px;
    background: #006699;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.catsecmenufx {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.catgorieswr {
    background: #F5F5F7;
    max-width: 1920px !important;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.catgorieswrm {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; 
}
.catgorieswr_1 {
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 100px 0 20px 40px
}
.catgorieswr_1_1 {
    color: #203860;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 45px
}
.catgorieswr_1_2 {
    color: #2C2F34;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 20px
}
.catgorieswr_2 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 100px 0 20px 40px
}
.catgorieswr_2 div {
    width: 350px;
    min-height: 450px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(150, 158, 164, 0.2);
    moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(150, 158, 164, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(150, 158, 164, 0.2);
}
.catgorieswr_2 div img {
    max-width: 330px;
    margin: 30px 0 80px
}
.catgorieswr_3 {
    margin: 10px 0 100px 495px
}
.catgorieswr_3 a {
    color: #F7971D;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.catgorieswr_3 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline
}
.pin-spacer {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Scroll</title>

    <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewport">
        <div id="content">
            <div>
                <div class="catsecmenuwr"></div>
                <div class="header"></div>
                <div class="catsecmenu defaulttm" id="catsecmenu"></div>
                <div class="videobanner"></div>
                <div class="catgorieswr horizontal">
                    <div class="pin-wrap">
                        <div class="catgorieswrm animation-wrap to-right">
                            <div class="catgorieswr_1">
                                <div class="catgorieswr_1_1">
                                    Live Streaming Solutions
                                </div>
                                <div class="catgorieswr_1_2">
                                    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="catgorieswr_2">
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="catgorieswr_3">
                            <a href="https://test.bzbgear.com/homepagescroll.html">Cameras and Broadcasting Equipment&gt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="https://test.bzbgear.com/homepagescroll.html">Applications and Solutions&gt;</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="catgorieswr horizontal">
                    <div class="pin-wrap">
                        <div class="catgorieswrm animation-wrap to-right">
                            <div class="catgorieswr_1">
                                <div class="catgorieswr_1_1">
                                    Pro Audio Visual Solutions
                                </div>
                                <div class="catgorieswr_1_2">
                                    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="catgorieswr_2">
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br>
                                    Cameras
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="catgorieswr_3">
                            <a href="https://test.bzbgear.com/homepagescroll.html">Cameras and Broadcasting Equipment&gt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="https://test.bzbgear.com/homepagescroll.html">Applications and Solutions&gt;</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section2"></div>
                <div class="section3"></div>
                <div class="section4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то это делается так:

```css
/* devanagari */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJbecmNE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJnecmNE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* devanagari */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z11lFc-K.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1JlFc-K.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1xlFQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* devanagari */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z11lFc-K.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z1JlFc-K.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z1xlFQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000
}

.videobanner {
  height: 619px;
  background: #ccc
}

.section2 {
  height: 500px;
  background: #333
}

.section3 {
  height: 500px;
  background: #e1e1e1
}

.section4 {
  height: 400px;
  background: #000
}

.catsecmenu {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 55px;
  background: #006699;
  z-index: 9999;
}


/* .catsecmenufx {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
} */

.catgorieswr {
  background: #F5F5F7;
  max-width: 1920px !important;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.catgorieswrm {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.catgorieswr_1 {
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px 0 20px 40px
}

.catgorieswr_1_1 {
  color: #203860;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 45px
}

.catgorieswr_1_2 {
  color: #2C2F34;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.catgorieswr_2 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 100px 0 20px 40px
}

.catgorieswr_2 div {
  width: 350px;
  min-height: 450px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(150, 158, 164, 0.2);
  moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(150, 158, 164, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(150, 158, 164, 0.2);
}

.catgorieswr_2 div img {
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 30px 0 80px
}

.catgorieswr_3 {
  margin: 10px 0 100px 495px
}

.catgorieswr_3 a {
  color: #F7971D;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.catgorieswr_3 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.pin-spacer {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
  <div id="content">
    <div>
      <div class="catsecmenuwr"></div>
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="catsecmenu defaulttm" id="catsecmenu"></div>
      <div class="videobanner"></div>
      <div class="catgorieswr horizontal">
        <div class="pin-wrap">
          <div class="catgorieswrm animation-wrap to-right">
            <div class="catgorieswr_1">
              <div class="catgorieswr_1_1">
                Live Streaming Solutions
              </div>
              <div class="catgorieswr_1_2">
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="catgorieswr_2">
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="catgorieswr_3">
            <a href="https://test.bzbgear.com/homepagescroll.html">Cameras and Broadcasting Equipment&gt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="https://test.bzbgear.com/homepagescroll.html">Applications and Solutions&gt;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="catgorieswr horizontal">
        <div class="pin-wrap">
          <div class="catgorieswrm animation-wrap to-right">
            <div class="catgorieswr_1">
              <div class="catgorieswr_1_1">
                Pro Audio Visual Solutions
              </div>
              <div class="catgorieswr_1_2">
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="catgorieswr_2">
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
              <div>
                <img alt="" src="./img/BG-NUCLEUS-10X_972_876.png"><br> Cameras
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="catgorieswr_3">
            <a href="https://test.bzbgear.com/homepagescroll.html">Cameras and Broadcasting Equipment&gt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="https://test.bzbgear.com/homepagescroll.html">Applications and Solutions&gt;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section2"></div>
      <div class="section3"></div>
      <div class="section4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Если Вы добавите JavaScript, который я использую, Ваше решение перестанет работать

Answer (score 0):

Решением было закрепление меню:

```
ScrollTrigger.create({
  trigger: ".catsecmenu",
  pin: true,
  pinSpacing: false,
  markers: true,
  end: () => ScrollTrigger.maxScroll(document.body),
  invlidateOnRefresh: true
})
```